# How to make Rest Spring work with JS

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

Folks

I have a problem with consuming a rest using javascript.

This Rest is already being used in other applications, where PHP and Aspx conserve the same described below.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/userlogin")
public class UserRest {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<RetornUser> login(@RequestBody User user) {
        RetornUser retornUser = new RetornUser();
        try {
            user = userService.autenticarUsuario(user);
            retornUser.setUsuario(usuario);
            retornUser.setCodigoRetorno(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            retornUser.setCodigoRetorno(-1);
            retornUser.setMensagem(e.getMessage());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(retornUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The code above works perfectly with PHP, Aspx and Java calls.

When I call the routine, the JS is falling into the error function before receiving the return.

The worst thing is that the JS error is not bringing the reason. Below the code in pure HTML.

```
function logar() {
    try {
        var json = JSON.stringify(usuario);
        json = "{\"nome\": \"garra\",\"senha\": \"1234\"}";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/garrasystem/webservice/userlogin/login",
            data: json,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 300000, // sets timeout to 3 seconds
            success: function (retorno) {
                alert(retorno);
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

The way it is there, when I send debug, it calls the normal login method, but it falls into the error function, nor does it expect the login method to perform the return.

I put the method return String only and nothing too.

My Spring is 4.

I'm waiting for some help

Vinicius Castro

Comment: Make sure you annotate your method with RequestResponse or annotate the class by RestController

Comment: I used RestController and I did not succeed. Do you have any examples with RequestResponse?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing `string` instead of json object. Could you try passing the following:

```
var data = {
    nome: "garra",
    senha: "1234"
};
```

Comment: Young! I did the same suggested. The problem is that it is not waiting for the return. When I send debug it calls the login method. Even before the login method finishes, JS already falls into the error function, and the login method has not yet finished the process.

Answer (score 0):

Folks
Being focused on a single problem, I forgot to analyze the button type. It was like type submit, so it was not working. It is like experiencing these kind of mistakes.

Thank you to all who supported me